# How to check if an array has an element that is not integer?

Tags: perl

Firstly, I have a hash:
`$hWriteHash{'Identifier'}{'number'}` that contains = `1#2#12#A24#48`

Then I split this by "#" and then put it in the `@arr_of_tenors` variable.

Here's the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
use Data::Dumper;

$nums = $hWriteHash{'Identifier'}{'number'};
my @arr_of_tenors = split("#", $nums);
print("@arr_of_tenors\n");
```

The output is `1 2 12 A24 48`

Now, my goal is if the array has an element that's not an integer which is `A24`, it will go to die function.

Here's what I've tried.

```
if(not looks_like_number(@arr_of_tenors)){
    die "ERROR: Array has an element that's not an integer.";
}else{
    print("All good");
}
```

Obviously, the only acceptable format should be integers only.

I've tried to use `looks_like_number` but it didn't work. It always goes to else statement.
I know that there is another option which is grep + regex. But as much as possible, I don't want to use regular expressions on this one if there is a function that does the same job. Also, as much as possible, I don't want to iterate each element.

How does `looks_like_number` works?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's yet another way:

```
use Types::Common qw( Int );

if ( Int->all( @arr_of_tenors ) ) {
  # all integers
}
else {
  # at least one non-integer
}
```

And another, because why not?

```
use Types::Common qw( ArrayRef Int );

if ( ArrayRef->of( Int )->check( \@arr_of_tenors ) ) {
  # all integers
}
else {
  # at least one non-integer
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> How does looks_like_number works? Am I missing something?

It checks one thing at a time, you fed many things (an array). You need to traverse those many things and make a decision.

You want to error out if *not all* of the elements look like an integer, right? Then you can use [`notall`](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#notall) from the core module List::Util:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(notall);

my $nums = "1#2#12#A24#48";  # $hWriteHash{"Identifier"}{"number"};
my @arr_of_tenors = split("#", $nums);

if (notall { /^-?\d+\z/ } @arr_of_tenors) {
    die "ERROR: Array has an element that doesn't look like an integer.";
}
else {
    print "All good\n";
}
```

which dies with

> ERROR: Array has an element that doesn't look like an integer.

The `notall` function performs the mentioned traversal for you and subjects the predicate (the block above) to each element of the list in turn. Returns true if not all of the elements satisfies the condition; false otherwise. It also shortcircuits, i.e., immediately returns true if it sees a noncomplying element.

Noting that i changed `looks_like_number` to an [integer check](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#How-do-I-determine-whether-a-scalar-is-a-number%2fwhole%2finteger%2ffloat%3f) with a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jCXTEZ/1) as the former accepts more, e.g., 48.7 etc. But if you are sure the incoming values are integer-like, you can replace the regex with `looks_like_number($_)` in the block above.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [List::Util::any](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#all) to check if any element of the array does not look like a number:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
use Data::Dumper;
use List::Util qw(any);

my $sKey = 'abc';
my %hWriteHash;
$hWriteHash{$sKey}{'number'} = '1#2#12#A24#48';
my $nums = $hWriteHash{$sKey}{'number'};
my @arr_of_tenors = split("#", $nums);
print("@arr_of_tenors\n");

if (any { not looks_like_number($_) } @arr_of_tenors) {
    die "ERROR: Array has an element that's not an integer.";
}else{
    print("All good");
}
print "\n";
```

From the docs:

> Many cases of using `grep` in a conditional can be written using `any`
> instead, as it can short-circuit after the first true result.

This works with the input you provided.  However, `looks_like_number` will also be true for numbers like `5.37`.